# How to convert a discrete array to continuous array using numpy?

Tags: numpy

I am having an array a = np.array([3,5,7,8,10]).
I want to convert this into b = ([0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]). Array b is basically pointing to the position in the array a (converting it to 0 and 1).
How can i do that ?. Intention is to use np.convolve to identify where there is a window of continuous numbers.
I have tried to use b = np.digitize(c,a), where c = np.arange(1,10,1). But it gives error both a, b are not in same size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
a.sort()
b = [1 if i in a else 0 for i in range(1,a[-1]+1)]
```

The output is `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

You can skip a.sort() if the array is already sorted.

Comment: Thanks. But length of array a is 150 million (distributed). length of array b will be fixed 200 million (with 0 and 1). Is there a way to do faster in numpy ?

Comment: Will something like `b = np.zeros(a[-1]+1); b[a] = 1; b = b[1:]` work?

Comment: If `b` is of fixed length with 200 million elements, you can do: `b = np.zeros(2_000_000_000, dtype=np.int8); b[a-1] = 1`.